# AWS Athena Query Result HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Unexpected end of input stream

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-athena

I have JSON data on s3 so I created external table with this data in Athena. I guess, somewhere in the data is missing as a format so I have received the error. Can I ignore this missing format of data? I am getting an error while querying the data

**Error :  HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Unexpected end of the input stream**

Thank you.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE yyyy.xxxxx
(
  `xxxx` struct<xxxxx<xxx>,xxxxxxx<xxxxxx>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xxxxxx` struct<xxxx<xxxxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx>,xxxxxx> COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `xxxx` struct<xxxxx> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xxxxx` struct<xxxxx,client:struct<xxxxx>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xxxxx` struct<xxxx> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xxx` struct<xxxxx> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xx` struct<xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xx` struct<xxxx> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `xxxx` string COMMENT 'from deserializer'
)
PARTITIONED BY (DAY INT,HOUR INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://fsdfsdf/**sfsfdsf*/sdfsdf'
*/
```

Comment: Take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-hive-cursor-error/

Comment: I looked this page but I didn't solve the problem. Thank you for support.